# Testing MUI checkbox with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-testing-library

In a react component I have a checkbox from Material UI with this markup:

```
<label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root">
   <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root PrivateSwitchBase-root-353 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary PrivateSwitchBase-checked-354 Mui-checked MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
         <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input-356" id="citizen-profile-challenge-checkbox-diabetes" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="other" checked="">
         <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
            <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
         </svg>
      </span>
      <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
   </span>
   <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label MuiTypography-body1">Other</span>
</label>
```

I'm trying to follow the guide lines by querying on the labels (in this case "Other") instead of using id's.

So I want to click the checkbox with label "Other" (`<span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label MuiTypography-body1">Other</span>`) and test that the value of Checkbox changes (`<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input-356" id="citizen-profile-challenge-checkbox-diabetes" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="other" checked="">`).

```
fireEvent.click(getByLabelText('Other', { selector: 'input' }))
const checked1 = (getByLabelText('Other', { selector: 'input' }) as HTMLInputElement).checked
console.log(checked1) // false

fireEvent.click(getByLabelText('Other', { selector: 'input' }))
const checked2 = (getByLabelText('Other', { selector: 'input' }) as HTMLInputElement).checked
console.log(checked2) // false

fireEvent.click(getByLabelText('Other'))
const checked3 = (getByLabelText('Other') as HTMLInputElement).checked
console.log(checked3) // false

fireEvent.click(getByLabelText('Other'))
const checked4 = (getByLabelText('Other') as HTMLInputElement).checked
console.log(checked4) // false
```

I tried different methods but `checked` remains `false`. Seems like instad I need to grab the sibling of the label span and search for the  there. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I found an possible explanation why the checkbox is not changing when being clicked...

The Checkbox is a controlled input managed by a parent component. So the state is actually not changing when clicking it here. Instead it's just calling a callback function (passed in from the props) `onChange`. So the proper way to test this is to check whether the callback is being called with the right arguments and payload.

I hope this helps others having the same kind of problem.

```
it('should clea field if "Other" is unchecked', (): void => {
    const citizen = {
        ...props.citizen,
        illnesses: [Challenge.Other],
        otherIllnesses: 'Blah...',
    }
    const { getByLabelText } = render(<CitizenProfileChallenges {...props} citizen={citizen} />)

    // arrange
    const checkboxLabel = 'Other'

    // act
    fireEvent.click(getByLabelText(checkboxLabel))

    // assert
    expect(props.onCitizenChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(props.onCitizenChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        ...
    })
})
```

Comment: How do I check that the checkbox has the property "checked" ?, when the structure of a Mui checkbox seems to have all kinds of nested Views

Answer (score -2):

I think you just need to use `addEventListener`, here an example.

```
document.getElementById("citizen-profile-challenge-checkbox-diabetes")
        .addEventListener("change", function changeHandler() {
          console.log(this.checked ? "checked!!" : "unchecked!!");
        });
```